# How to do Phone number format checking in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, phone-number

I have a form with phone number field, i need to validate it with the format on keypress. How to do this?
It will be like, some one enters a special characters except ( ) - or alphabet then and there it should show an alert, and if numeric digits are entered then it should get auto formatted like (999)-999-9999.
Can anyone help me how to do this in jquery or javascript??

Edit
I used this code below for jquery mask plugin
`$(#myid).mask("(999)-999-9999",{placeholder:" "});`
placeholder is used to replace the "_" underscores with blank. This works perfectly now.

Comment: @andyb i tried with regex but was unable to update it on keypress with the formatting, ie by adding the ()- automatically in the format. i was getting some improper behavior on backspace on keypress event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a plugin like jQuery [Masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick help, i used the masked plugin, and its work perfectly as i wanted, even the editing is also easy in the jquery for any other format checking. thanks @F.Calderan

Answer (score 1):

[Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) Will do the trick

```
////$("#your_text_box_id").mask("<FORMAT YOU WANT>");
$("#textbox id").mask("99/99/9999");
```